Dropdown Button is hidig behind the image div
Z-index, postion-absolute/relative, nothing is working.
    Test
    
    <a>1233</a>
    <a href="#">2322</a>
    <a>3444</a>
    
    
  
   

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app">
   <div class="portfolio" title="test">
          <a target="_blank"><img src="http://localhost/test/publication_assets/img/publication/jan.png" class="img-fluid" alt=""></a>
         </div>
</div>

z-index: 9999;
position: relative;

Where is drop down button? Please provide correct format code and CSS as well.
